# Material Design for Bootstrap (MDB) - "radial-gradient" has SASS compile issue

Tags: sass, frameworks

I am newbie and learning SASS, Compass and Sublime Text 3, and I found a free framework called MDB, but after compiled, the browser shows error as below:

Wrong number of arguments (1 for 2+) for `radial-gradient'

But weird thing is, after deleted two sentence in "_waves.scss", it compiled OK!

55) background: radial-gradient($gradient);

71) background: radial-gradient($gradient);

There is a user asked the author the same question as mine, but he think it is users developed environment problem.  [enter link description here](http://mdbootstrap.com/forums/topic/sass-error-wrong-number-of-arguments-1-for-2-for-radial-gradient/)

Does anyone knows the solve way?
I have tried to use @import "compass" at scss file, it is still not work.
Or only I can do is disable this radial-gradient effect?

Thank you

Comment: it can be outdated sass compiler, maybe you are using sass-rails? There are many issues on github describing that problem, and after update everything seems to work again

Comment: As the Alan said, something wrong may be with your environment. We use prepros to compile MDB sass files, so I recommend you to use it too

Comment: Thank you Mr. Alan and Matt, I will try it.

Comment: You ever solve this?  I'm running into the same issue with Prepros.